# contravariant problems with C# delegates on dictionaries

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling, covariance, contravariance

I have been developing for a while different event systems for games where the listener received a generic event-type object and had to distinguish its real type with a switch or similar and then cast to the correct subclass event.

After different aproaches I was able to get rid of the switch-case using a structure as follows (simplified):

```
public class Event {}
public class EventA : Event {}
public class EventB : Event {}

public delegate void HanlderDelegate(Event ev);

public class EventManager
{
    Dictionary<Type, HanlderDelegate> delegateMap = new Dictionary<Type, HanlderDelegate>();

    public void Dispatch(Event ev)
    {
        if (delegateMap.ContainsKey(ev.GetType()))
        {
            delegateMap[ev.GetType()].Invoke(ev);
        }
    }

    public void Register<T>(HanlderDelegate handler) where T : Event
    {
        delegateMap.Add(typeof(T), handler);
    }
}

public class EventListener
{
    public EventListener(EventManager evtMgr)
    {
        evtMgr.Register<EventA>(this.HandleEventA);
        evtMgr.Register<EventB>(this.HandleEventB);
    }

    public void HandleEventA(Event ev)
    {
        EventA evA = (EventA)ev;
        //... do stuff
    }

    public void HandleEventB(Event ev)
    {
        EventB evB = (EventB)ev;
        //... do stuff
    }
}
```

I'm quite happy with this approach, but I still find the casting in each method improvable. I tried to make the delegate more generic

`public delegate void HanlderDelegate<T>(T ev) where T : Event;` so listeners could directly implement `public void HandleEvent(EventA ev)` and `public void HandleEvent(EventB ev)` and register them.
But of course, the dictionary in the EventManager class should store pointers to `HanlderDelegate<Event>`, and there's where problems begin, I cannot cast `HanlderDelegate<EventA>` to `HanlderDelegate<Event>` in order to store them, and at the same time casting it the other way to invoke them.

Is there a way to achieve this? I know the compiler would allow weird stuff, but I'm aware of it and can control by code that EventB is not incorrectly being casted to EventA and so on.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the delegate and the `Dispatch` method generic, and store the handlers as `Delegate` rather than `HandlerDelegate<T>`:

```
delegate void HandlerDelegate<TEvent>(TEvent ev) where TEvent : Event;

class EventManager
{
    Dictionary<Type, Delegate> delegateMap = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent ev) where TEvent : Event
    {
        Delegate d;
        if (delegateMap.TryGetValue(typeof(TEvent), out d))
        {
            var handler = (HandlerDelegate<TEvent>)d;
            handler(ev);
        }
    }

    public void Register<TEvent>(HandlerDelegate<TEvent> handler) where TEvent : Event
    {
        delegateMap.Add(typeof(TEvent), handler);
    }
}
```

Of course, you still have to cast in the `Dispatch` method, but at this point you know that the cast is correct.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! Having the Type Delegate in the dictionary allows the delegates to be generic and solves that part. Never tought of it. I've also noticed that Delegate class can call DynamicInvoke without the need of casting. Is there any difference, like performance or so? Because setting the Dispatch method generic limits the possibility of, for example, queueing all events before dispatching them.